# Лилипут и карлик

Tags: этимология, этикет

Происхождение слова "лилипут" всем известно - его придумал Свифт. А вот как быть с карликами? Биологически они отличаются от лилипутов и, соответственно, отличается название.
Я могу предположить, что придворных шутов маленького роста часто звали Карлами, поэтому за ними закрепилось это прозвище уже как нарицательное. Но это моя версия, а как все на самом деле? И к тому же интересно, если у слова такое происхождение, не является ли оно оскорбительным для людей с таким отклонением?

Answer (score 1):

"Оскорбительным" может быть не слово, а отношение. Ну, а вполне убедительную версию происхождения этого слова [даёт Фасмер](http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Karlik-918.html).

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить, что карлик - это русское слово калека, а в древнерусском - калика.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, на чем основаны ваши выводы.

Comment: Вывод у меня только один-это созвучие. Так же предположу, что английское hello, родственно слову: шалом, салам...

Comment: Ещё, карлик и калика как бы виден один корень в словах и смысл.